XAMPP Apache not running? How to fix?
I have installed the XAMPP from their website and having trouble starting apache. I have installed the service as well by clicking the box at the left and still not working.

In the httpd.conf file, I have replaced the Listen 80 to Listen 8080 but still no luck. I'm not sure what's the problem and in the error.log, it's giving this errors:
[Thu Aug 08 19:10:32.070432 2024] [core:warn] [pid 9076:tid 424] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
PHP Warning:  'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.29 in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Aug 08 19:10:32.110592 2024] [:emerg] [pid 9076:tid 424] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting


The apache http server fails to start because you are using the integrated php module, which is installed in an incompatible build variant. That is what the error message says.
